# WinForms - When printing two datagridviews, print preview is good but on paper only 2nd dgv is printed

Tags: c#, winforms, printing, datagridview, print-preview

I am making a software to help me at work. It reads two excel (xlsx) files and get some info from them. Then it put the info in one of the two datagridviews or in both datagridviews.

Then i have a number that i need to show when i print the datagridviews. In print preview all is exactly as i want but when printing on paper it removes (or doesn't remember) everything about first datagridview and anything i print with it and start from the 2nd datagridview.

Here how it shows in print preview:

[image: Print preview]

but when i print it on paper i get like this

[image: Printed on paper]

Why the first datagridview gone on paper but if i print it PDF from Microsoft print to PDF i get PDF that has exactly as the preview.

Problem only when printing on paper.

Here is my printing code https://pastebin.com/6ZF2FevZ

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Printing;
using System.Drawing.Text;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Motabaka
{
  class DGVsPrinter
  {
      private Font fontD;
      private Brush brushD = Brushes.Black;
      private bool dgv1Finished;
      private string a3800, a1800;

      public string Title { get; set; }
      public bool IncludeDateAndTimeInFooter { get; set; }
      public bool IncludePageNumberInFooter { get; set; }
      public bool IncludeEndingPhraseAtTheEnd { get; set; }
      public string EndingPhrase { get; set; } = "End";

      private DataGridView dataGridView1, dataGridView2;
      private int rowIndex;
      private int cellCount;
      private int pageNumber = 1;
      private readonly PrintDocument printDoc;
      private int iTotalWidth1;
      private int iTotalWidth2;
      private Dictionary<int, int> ColumntWidths;
      private Dictionary<int, int> arrColumnWidths1 = new Dictionary<int, int>();
      private Dictionary<int, int> arrColumnWidths2 = new Dictionary<int, int>();
      private bool preview;

      public DGVsPrinter(DataGridView dataGridView1, DataGridView dataGridView2, PrintDocument printDoc, string A3800, string A1800)
      {
          this.dataGridView1 = dataGridView1;
          this.dataGridView2 = dataGridView2;
          this.printDoc = printDoc;
          fontD = new Font(dataGridView1.Font, FontStyle.Bold);

          printDoc.BeginPrint += OnBeginPrint;
          printDoc.PrintPage += OnPrintPage;
          a3800 = A3800;
          a1800 = A1800;
      }

      public void Print(bool preview = false)
      {
          this.preview = preview;

          rowIndex = 0;
          cellCount = 0;
          pageNumber = 0;

          var dgvs = new DataGridView[] { dataGridView1, dataGridView2 };
          foreach (DataGridView dgv in dgvs)
          {
              var rows = dgv.Rows
              .Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
              .FirstOrDefault(r => !r.IsNewRow && r.Visible);

              if (rows != null)
                  cellCount = rows.Cells
                      .Cast<DataGridViewCell>()
                      .Where(c => c.Visible)
                      .Count();

              if (cellCount == 0)
              {
                  //MessageBox.Show(new Form() { FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None }, "Nothing to print...");
                  continue;
              }
          }

          if (cellCount == 0)
          {
              MessageBox.Show(new Form() { FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None }, "Nothing to print...");
              return;
          }

          if (preview)
          {
              try
              {
                  using (var pd = new PrintPreviewDialog())
                  {
                      pd.Document = printDoc;
                      pd.ShowDialog();
                  }
              }
              catch (Exception ex)
              {
                  Error.Log(ex);
              }
          }
          else
          {
              try
              {
                  using (var pd = new PrintDialog())
                  {
                      pd.Document = printDoc;
                      if (pd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                      {
                          pd.Document.Print();
                      }
                  }
              }
              catch (Exception ex)
              {
                  Error.Log(ex);
              }
          }
      }

      private void OnBeginPrint(object sender, PrintEventArgs e)
      {
          try
          {
              rowIndex = 0; pageNumber = 1;
              iTotalWidth1 = 0;
              iTotalWidth2 = 0;
              arrColumnWidths1.Clear();
              arrColumnWidths2.Clear();

              foreach (DataGridViewColumn dgvGridCol in dataGridView1.Columns)
              {
                  if (!dgvGridCol.Visible) { continue; }

                  iTotalWidth1 += dgvGridCol.Width;
              }

              foreach (DataGridViewColumn dgvGridCol in dataGridView2.Columns)
              {
                  if (!dgvGridCol.Visible) { continue; }

                  iTotalWidth2 += dgvGridCol.Width;
              }
          }
          catch (Exception ex)
          {
              Error.Log(ex, "Error while printing [OnBeginPrint]");
          }
      }

      private void OnPrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
      {
          try
          {
              e.Graphics.Clear(Color.White);

              var w = e.MarginBounds.Width / cellCount;
              var x = e.MarginBounds.X;
              var y = e.MarginBounds.Y;
              int h;
              Rectangle rec;

              while (true)
              {
                  var dgv = !dgv1Finished ? dataGridView1 : dataGridView2;
                  ColumntWidths = (dgv == dataGridView1) ? arrColumnWidths1 : arrColumnWidths2;
                  var totalWidths = (dgv == dataGridView1) ? iTotalWidth1 : iTotalWidth2;

                  var iTmpWidth = 0;
                  if (pageNumber == 1)
                  {
                      for (int i = dgv.Columns.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                      {
                          DataGridViewColumn GridCol = dgv.Columns[i];

                          if (!GridCol.Visible) continue;

                          iTmpWidth = (int)(Math.Floor(GridCol.Width /
                                         (double)totalWidths * totalWidths *
                                         (e.MarginBounds.Width / (double)totalWidths)));

                          if (!ColumntWidths.Keys.Contains(GridCol.Index))
                          {
                              ColumntWidths.Add(GridCol.Index, iTmpWidth);
                          }
                      }
                  }

                  using (var sf = new StringFormat())
                  {
                      sf.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
                      sf.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;
                      
                      sf.FormatFlags = StringFormatFlags.DirectionRightToLeft;
                      sf.Trimming = StringTrimming.None;

                      e.Graphics.TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint.ClearTypeGridFit;

                      // Uncomment to print the headers in the first page only.
                      //if (pageNumber == 1)
                      //{
                      h = dgv.RowTemplate.Height + 20;

                      #region Title
                      var TextToDraw = dgv.Tag?.ToString();
                      var xCenter = e.MarginBounds.Left + e.MarginBounds.Width / 2;

                      e.Graphics.DrawString(TextToDraw, fontD, brushD, xCenter, y - 20, sf);
                      #endregion

                      using (var strf = new StringFormat())
                      {
                          strf.Alignment = StringAlignment.Far;
                          strf.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Near;

                          #region Amount
                          var amount = (dgv == dataGridView1) ? a1800 : a3800;
                          var XC = e.MarginBounds.Right;
                          var font = new Font(dgv.Font.FontFamily, 12f, FontStyle.Regular);

                          e.Graphics.DrawString(amount, font, brushD, XC, y - 20, strf);
                          #endregion
                      }

                      for (int i = dgv.Columns.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                      {
                          var col = dgv.Columns[i];

                          if (col.Visible)
                          {
                              w = ColumntWidths[col.Index];
                              rec = new Rectangle(x, y, w, h);

                              e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.AliceBlue, rec);
                              e.Graphics.DrawString(
                                  col.HeaderText,
                                  col.DataGridView.Font,
                                  Brushes.Black,
                                  rec,
                                  sf);
                              //Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Black, 1.3f);
                              //pen.Alignment = PenAlignment.Inset;
                              //e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, rec);
                              Color[] colors;
                              if (false)
                              {
                                  colors = new Color[]
                                  {
              SystemColors.ControlDark,
              SystemColors.ControlDarkDark,
              SystemColors.ControlLightLight,
              SystemColors.ControlLight
                                  };
                              }
                              else
                              {
                                  colors = new Color[]
                                  {
              SystemColors.ControlLightLight,
              SystemColors.ControlLight,
              SystemColors.ControlDark,
              SystemColors.ControlDarkDark
                                  };
                              }
                              using (Pen p = new Pen(colors[0]))
                              {
                                  e.Graphics.DrawLine(p, rec.X, rec.Bottom - 1,
                                      rec.X, rec.Y);
                                  e.Graphics.DrawLine(p, rec.X, rec.Y,
                                      rec.Right - 1, rec.Y);
                              }
                              using (Pen p = new Pen(colors[1]))
                              {
                                  e.Graphics.DrawLine(p, rec.X + 1, rec.Bottom - 2,
                                      rec.X + 1, rec.Y + 1);
                                  e.Graphics.DrawLine(p, rec.X + 1, rec.Y + 1,
                                      rec.Right - 2, rec.Y + 1);
                              }
                              using (Pen p = new Pen(colors[2]))
                              {
                                  e.Graphics.DrawLine(p, rec.X, rec.Bottom - 1,
                                      rec.Right - 1, rec.Bottom - 1);
                                  e.Graphics.DrawLine(p, rec.Right - 1, rec.Bottom - 1,
                                      rec.Right - 1, rec.Y);
                              }
                              using (Pen p = new Pen(colors[3]))
                              {
                                  e.Graphics.DrawLine(p, rec.X + 1, rec.Bottom - 2,
                                      rec.Right - 2, rec.Bottom - 2);
                                  e.Graphics.DrawLine(p, rec.Right - 2, rec.Bottom - 2,
                                      rec.Right - 2, rec.Y + 1);
                              }

                              x += w;
                          }
                      }

                      x = e.MarginBounds.X;
                      y += h;
                      //}

                      /*Drawing the rows with their content*/
                      for (var i = rowIndex; i < dgv.RowCount; i++)
                      {
                          var row = dgv.Rows[i];

                          if (!row.Visible) continue;

                          if (row.IsNewRow) break;

                          h = GetRowHeight(e.Graphics, row, e.MarginBounds, sf);

                          if (h > e.MarginBounds.Height)
                          {
                              MessageBox.Show("Insufficient height.");
                              e.Cancel = true;
                              return;
                          }

                          /*Drawing row's cells with their content*/
                          for (int r = row.Cells.Count - 1; r >= 0; r--)
                          {
                              var cell = row.Cells[r];
                              if (!cell.Visible) { continue; }

                              w = ColumntWidths[cell.ColumnIndex];
                              rec = new Rectangle(x, y, w, h);

                              if (rec.Bottom > e.MarginBounds.Bottom)
                              {
                                  pageNumber++;
                                  rowIndex = i;
                                  e.HasMorePages = true;
                                  return;
                              }

                              var color = (cell.InheritedStyle.BackColor == Color.Yellow) ? new SolidBrush(SystemColors.Window) : new SolidBrush(cell.InheritedStyle.BackColor);
                              e.Graphics.FillRectangle(color, rec);
                              e.Graphics.DrawString(
                                  cell.FormattedValue.ToString(),
                                  dgv.Font,
                                  Brushes.Black,
                                  rec,
                                  sf);
                              e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, rec);

                              x += rec.Width;
                          }/*Done drawing the cells in a row*/

                          x = e.MarginBounds.X;
                          y += h;
                      }/*Done drawing all the rows*/

                      #region Date and time
                      if (IncludeDateAndTimeInFooter)
                      {
                          var strDate = DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString() + " " + DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString();
                          var wdate = e.Graphics.MeasureString(strDate, fontD, e.MarginBounds.Height, sf).Width;
                          var hdate = e.Graphics.MeasureString(strDate, fontD, e.MarginBounds.Height, sf).Height;
                          
                          var yBottom = e.MarginBounds.Height + e.MarginBounds.Top;

                          var recDate = new Rectangle(e.MarginBounds.X, yBottom, e.MarginBounds.Width, (int)hdate);
                          //e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.LightSkyBlue, recDate);
                          e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, recDate);
                          e.Graphics.DrawString(strDate, fontD, brushD, recDate.X, yBottom);
                      }
                      #endregion
                      #region Page Number
                      if (IncludePageNumberInFooter)
                      {
                          var pNumber = "Page " + pageNumber;
                          var yBottom = e.MarginBounds.Height + e.MarginBounds.Top;
                          
                          var xRight = e.MarginBounds.Left + (e.MarginBounds.Width - e.Graphics.MeasureString(pNumber, fontD, e.MarginBounds.Width, sf).Width);

                          e.Graphics.DrawString(pNumber, fontD, brushD, xRight, yBottom);
                      }
                      #endregion

                      y = y + 70;
                      rowIndex = 0;
                      dgv1Finished = true;
                      e.HasMorePages = (dgv == dataGridView1);
                  }

                  if (!e.HasMorePages)
                  {
                      if (IncludeEndingPhraseAtTheEnd)
                      {
                          using (var strf = new StringFormat())
                          {
                              strf.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;
                              strf.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
                              strf.FormatFlags = StringFormatFlags.DirectionRightToLeft;

                              var fontD = new Font(dgv.Font, FontStyle.Bold);
                              var brushD = Brushes.Black;
                              var xCenter = e.MarginBounds.Left + e.MarginBounds.Width / 2;
                              var yBottom = e.MarginBounds.Top
                                  + e.MarginBounds.Height
                                  + e.Graphics.MeasureString(EndingPhrase, fontD, e.MarginBounds.Height, strf).Height;

                              e.Graphics.DrawString(EndingPhrase, fontD, brushD, xCenter, y - 60, strf);
                          }
                      }

                      break;
                  }
              }
          }
          catch (Exception ex)
          {
              Error.Log(ex, " Error while printing [OnPrintPage]");
          }
      }

      private int GetRowHeight(
  Graphics g,
  DataGridViewRow row,
  Rectangle bounds,
  StringFormat sf,
  int minHeight = 22)
      {
          var cells = row.Cells.OfType<DataGridViewTextBoxCell>()
              .Where(c => c.Visible);

          if (cells == null) return minHeight;

          /*(longest, next) => next.Length > longest.Length ? next : longest*/
          var cell = cells.Aggregate((DataGridViewTextBoxCell)null, (x, y) => (x != null) && (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x.FormattedValue.ToString()) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(y.FormattedValue.ToString())) &&
          (x.FormattedValue.ToString().Length > y.FormattedValue.ToString().Length) ? x : y);


          if (cell == null) return minHeight;
          var h = g.MeasureString(cell.FormattedValue.ToString(),
              row.DataGridView.Font,
              new SizeF(ColumntWidths[cell.ColumnIndex], bounds.Height),
              sf).ToSize().Height;

          return Math.Max(h + 10, minHeight); // 6 for top and bottom margins...
      }


  }
}
```

I call the print like this

```
var print = new DGVsPrinter(dataGridView1, dataGridView2, printDocument1, Final3800L.Text, Final1800L.Text)
            {
                IncludeDateAndTimeInFooter = true,
                IncludePageNumberInFooter = true
            };
            print.Print(true);
```

Comment: @KJ I tried to increase the top margin it still prints the same thing but at lower position and not near the top (as i increase the margin) it's like the first datagridview and the number and text above it doesn't exists.
If i print one datagridview with other text everything prints good. 
I have set these margins `pageSetupDialog1.PageSettings.Margins = new Margins(50, 100, 40, 70);`

Comment: @KJ I found the problem. 

If i print it by print dialog it prints good. But when i show the preview it do this problem. Because i didn't set **dgv1Finished** to **false** on **OnBeginPrint**. 

when it actually prints It runs the code again and dgv1Finished is already **true** after the preview so it get datagridview2 first and nothing about datagridvie1. 

I only have to set **dgv1Finished = false** in **OnBeginPrint** and now it prints everything.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem.

If i print it by print dialog it prints good. But when i show the preview, this problem happens. Because i **didn't set dgv1Finished to false** on **OnBeginPrint**.

when it actually prints It runs the code again and dgv1Finished is already true after the preview so it get datagridview2 first and nothing about datagridvie1.

I only have to set **dgv1Finished = false** in **OnBeginPrint** and now it prints everything.